# Angular 5 internationalization workflow

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, internationalization

my current process is as follows:

#### Current process

I add the i18n attributes to the template.
Then I execute `ng xi18n`. This creates the messages.xlf file.
As soon as the process is finished, you have to copy messages.xlf and change the file extension to `*.fr.xlf`. In the renamed file you now manually search for all `<source>` tags and add the `<target>` tags with the translation.

If there are many different languages, this process is very time-consuming.

#### Problem

The problems here are the missing versioning of the translations and especially the manual adding of the `<target>` tags to the corresponding `<source>` tags.

#### Desired workflow

It would be desirable to have a workflow where versioning is possible and above all, the desired translation files are created automatically.

*Would webpack be the right approach to solve this problem?*

Comment: using xliff people expect you to use some translation management software like eg. https://locize.com - not doing that work manually. Without tool support i would suggest like below going for a non-xliff i18n lib using pure json -> eg. https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next

Answer (score 0):

I just abandoned built in translation and prefered [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) module.

With it you can :
 - auto-extract translation string from source code
 - build one app that contains all locales
 - change locale during run time

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an IDE that supports regex searches, then you can use regexes for search and replace such as

```
search: (\s*)<source>([^<]*)</source>
replace: $1\n$2<target>$3</target>
```

This will add a `target` after every source.

And about updating the translations, you are supposed to have a versioning tool, that will highlight the changes in the file. All you have to do is keep it updated at every commit you do that involves this file.

I agree that this isn't practical, and so is the fact that you can't translate typescript code. But those are workarounds that you can use in the meantime to ease your life.